# Use THC hydra to make dictionary attack on localhost

Tags: brute-force, penetration-testing, hydra, dictionary-attack

I have programmed a log in in my webpage and now I want to test it against a dictionary attack. I am using Apache and my website is not online so to access it I connect to localhost/website 
In hydra I am using the command

`hydra -l username -P passList.txt localhost/website http-post-form "/logIn.php:user=^USER^&pass=^PASS:forgot"`

But it terminates with error

`[DATA] attacking service http-post-form on port 80
[ERROR] could not resolve address: localhost/website
0 of 1 target completed, 0 valid passwords found
[ERROR] 1 target did not resolve or could not be connected`

What is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

use the ip address somewhere localhost for example :

hydra -l username -P passList.txt 127.0.0.1/website http-post-form "/logIn.php:user=^USER^&pass=^PASS:forgot"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
hydra -l username -P passList.txt localhost http-post-form \
    "/website/logIn.php:user=^USER^&pass=^PASS:forgot"
```